# Using Core java need to read html file and fetch attribute value from the page

Tags: java, html, arrays

As per my requirement I need to read a html file in every 5 sec and from there I need to find the test case name and  pass and fail status if there is any new file and need to create a html report and need to write there.
I have done with below code.Is I am going right way.

Here I have convert the html file into text file then I have put the test cases name in a array .After that I am searching the text case name in that text file.Inside the text file the text cases is like in this format "RAP_45 1".Here RAP_45 is test case name "1" means pass and "0" means fail.My error is whatever I put inside array "0"  or "1" base on that only I am getting result not base on input file .Kindly help me out the condition I have tried its not working below.Please give a suggestion.

```
   public class HtmlReport {
       
        public static final String FOLDER = ("C:\\Users\\jdutta\\files");
     
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         
            System.out.println("Searching for new file....");
            final long pollingInterval = 5 * 1000;
     
            File folder = new File(FOLDER);
     
            if (!folder.exists()) {
               
                throw new RuntimeException("Directory not found: " + FOLDER);
            }
     
            FileAlterationObserver observer = new FileAlterationObserver(folder);
            FileAlterationMonitor monitor =
                    new FileAlterationMonitor(pollingInterval);
            FileAlterationListener listener = new FileAlterationListenerAdaptor() {
                
                @Override
                public void onFileCreate(File file) {
                    try {
                         System.out.println("File created: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
                          FileReader reader = new FileReader(file.getCanonicalPath());
                          // System.out.println(extractText(reader));
                            extractText(reader);
                        
                    }
                            
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    }
                }
     
                // Is triggered when a file is deleted from the monitored folder
                @Override
                public void onFileDelete(File file) {
                    try {
                        // "file" is the reference to the removed file
                        System.out.println("File removed: "
                                + file.getCanonicalPath());
                        // "file" does not exists anymore in the location
                        System.out.println("File still exists in location: "
                                + file.exists());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                    }
                }
            };
     
            observer.addListener(listener);
            monitor.addObserver(observer);
            monitor.start();
            
        }
    
        
        public static String extractText(Reader reader) throws IOException {
            
            String s[]={"RAP_45 1","RAP_50 0","RAP_75 0","RAP_PayAsYouGo 0","RAP_Refill_Coupon 0"};
            
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            FileWriter writeReport = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\jdutta\\files\\ResultSummary.html");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writeReport);
            String line;
            bw.write("<html><Body  font=\"14px/1.4 Georgia\" ><br><table border=\"2%\" width=\"50%\"><h3 >Summary:</h3><tr bgcolor=\"black\">");        
            bw.write("<div border=\"1px solid\"  color=\" #ccc\"   padding=\"50px\"> <th><font color=\"white\">Test</th> <th><font color=\"white\">Passed</th><th><font color=\"white\">Failed</th> <th><font color=\"white\">Execution time</th>");
            
            while ( (line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                
              sb.append(line);  
            }
            String textOnly = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString()).text();
            int pass=0;
            int fail=0;
          for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
              String[] s1=s[i].split(" ");
            System.out.println("s1.........."+s1[1]);
              
            if(textOnly.contains(s1[0])&& s1[1].contains("1")){
                
                  System.out.println(s[i]+"pass");
                  bw.write("<tr><td>" + s1[0] +  "</td><td>" + "1" + "</td><td>" + "0" + "</td><td>" 
                        + "200sec" + "</td></td></tr>");
                  
                  ++pass;
                
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("fail"+s1[0]);
                  bw.write("<tr><td>" + s1[0] +  "</td><td>" + "0" + "</td><td>" + "1" + "</td><td>" 
                            + "200sec" + "</td></tr>");
                  ++fail;
            }
      
          }
          bw.write("<tr><td>" + "Total" +  "</td><td>" + pass + "</td><td>" + fail + "</td></tr>");
        
          bw.write("</tr></table></Body></html>");
          bw.close();
          return  textOnly;
        }
        
       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to read attributes from HTML file and take action according to it.
Now HTML is simply XML files. You can try JAXB to unmarshal the tags and use it.
Haven't tried it yet but you should give it a try.

Or may be you can use JSoup

[jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)

Comment: Yaa but here I am using Jsoup...Can you please check the condition where i did mistak.